# htaccess redirect to a maintainance file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess in the public directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /sub/web1/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # HERE I NEED SOM MAGICAL ONELINER TO REDIRECT STUFF TO MAINTENANCE.HTML
    # BUT NO IDEA HOW TO WRITE IT ;(

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and I want to add some rule inside, so when I uncomment the rule, all links that hit `http://example.com/sub/web1/` or any files down that line, will be redirected to `http://example.com/sub/web1/maintenance.html`

I have tried to add:
`DirectoryIndex maintenance.html`
but this only redirects `http://example.com/sub/web1/`, if I have some subfolder or specific files like `http://example.com/sub/web1/posts`, it is useless.

Is there some oneliner that can even pull the domain name so it hasn't have to be typed absolutely? So, the `example.com` - or whatever domain - is not needed to type in the rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a rule like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /sub/web1/

    # uncomment line below to route everything to maintenance.html
    # RewriteRule !^maintenance\.html$ maintenance.html [L,NC]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # HERE I NEED SOM MAGICAL ONELINER TO REDIRECT STUFF TO MAINTENANCE.HTML
    # BUT NO IDEA HOW TO WRITE IT ;(

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this has already been answered and accepted, it's worth mentioning that if your maintenance page is temporary, you really should be returning the right http response, otherwise search engines might drop or re-index pages incorrectly.

At my company we use something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/holding/holding.html -f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/holding/holding.enable -f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !holding.html
RewriteRule ^.*$ /holding/holding.html [R=503,L]
ErrorDocument 503 /holding/holding.html
```

We create holding.html as the maintenance page, and then *touch* holding.enable to make the server switch to it without requiring a restart (not forgetting to *rm* it when we're done).  The *503* return code on the rewrite rule, and the *ErrorDocument 503* ensure that search engines see this a temporary outage and don't start de-listing our pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the %{HTTP_HOST} variable to get  the current domain that was used when hitting the given htaccess file - here's a handy cheat sheet of things:

[askapache - cheatsheet](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html)

And some examples

[askapache - examples](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html)

Although it's worth trying this out as it'll use root ^$ and rewrite that to the sub directory you want to use:

```
RewriteBase /
ReqwriteRule ^$ /sub/web1/
```

Comment: And what should I type in my case?

Comment: Try the amends I just added - might find that works ;)